# facing issue with unmarshalling an old xml ,after class structure got changed

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am struggling with unmarshalling an old xml file whose structure is different than my current object structure.

Previous structure

```
@xmlRootElement("configData")
public class configData{  
 private string name; 
 private string age; 
 private customObject obj;
}
```

My current data structure is

```
@xmlRootElement("configData")
public class configData{  
  List<SampleData> sampleDatas;;

}

public class SampleData{
  private string name; 
  private string age; 
  private customObject obj;

 }
```

How to make it work with old xml file. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You could delegate accessor methods to `configData`, and marking the list `@XmlTransient`...

Comment: I am new to JAXB mapping. How will  **@xmlTransient**  help in this case? Can you please elaborate a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your old structure suggest, that only one set of `SampleData` exists in the XML file.
So You should try something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ConfigData
{
  // This will hide the list from JAXB
  @XmlTransient
  private final List<SampleData> sampleDatas = new ArrayList<>();

  private SampleData getFirstSample()
  {
    if(sampleDatas.isEmpty())
      sampleDatas.add(new SampleData());
    return sampleDatas.get(0);
  }

  // Façade methods to delegate functionality to the list's first item...
  // Only setters are required, if you just want to read in an old format.
  // However this would not be optional, if you want to save to the new format...
  public void setName(String name)
  {
    getFirstSample().setName(name);
  }

  public void seAge(String age)
  {
    getFirstSample().setAge(age);
  }

  public void setObj(CustomObject obj)
  {
    getFirstSample().setObj(obj);
  }
}

public class SampleData
{
  private String name; 
  private String age; 
  private CustomObject obj;
  // Accessor methods...
}
```

The façade setter methods in ConfigData store thier values to the List's first item.

To provide the possibility to save, you should remove the `@XmlTransient`, and provide `public` getters to the fields you want to save...

Comment: Thanks for giving time to solving my problem. Yes, you are right. old XML file has one set of sample data. But, how will I get the value of properties in a first `sampleData` object, unless I copied the properties in `configData` class too?  I need to save data in new format.

Comment: I am not getting the properties value in my first `SampleData` object. it's always null for the old XML file.

Comment: Thanks!!! It's working. I applied `@xmlElement` annotation to all setters in `configData` class